# QGIS: Edits in attribute table are not updated in Postgis database. Why?

Tags: qgis, postgis, database

As the title say. I edit values in the attribute tables of my QGIS project but there is no update to the database. I refreshed in QGIS as well as the database.

What else do I need to do?

Comment: Has the user you are using to connect the grant to write the table?

Comment: I think so...editing values directly in database is possible (with pgAdmin3)

Comment: Do you receive an error? Can you paste here the error?

Comment: no...nothing happens...I made a screen video, but it can't be uploaded

Comment: Are you editing when you change the values? Are you connecting with the same username/password as PgAdminIII? Is there anything in the logs on PostgreSQL?

Comment: The problem was rather simple..I found it yesterday. the edited cell must not be marked when saving...thx for your help anyway!